# "A matter of typography" vs. "A subject of typography"

Tags: word-choice

A sentence from a technical manual I'm working on:

> Spaces that are a **matter** of typography rather than punctuation (= spaces that only a typographer knows about), such as a hair space after an opening quotation mark and before a closing one, are removed.

Which word is preferable to use in the above sentence, *matter* or *subject*?

Comment: Use ***matter*** (or perhaps ***issue***). The word ***subject*** refers to much broader concepts than just the use of spaces. Alternatively, rephrase to something where you don't need to make that choice: *Spaces that are [purely] typographic[al] rather than **concerned with** punctuation...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Matter' is correct. Although this kind of 'matter' may be synonymous with the word 'subject', they are not interchangeable. A 'matter' usually either an emergent situation or a component of a broader subject.

If there is a subject in this specific context, it is 'typography', not the 'space. A space is being classified as a matter that falls under the subject of typography.

Answer (score 3):

"Matter" and "subject" have similar meaning, but you can't use "subject" here. Just as a matter of usage, you can't say, "that are a subject of ..." with this definition* of "subject". I'm struggling to think what the general rule that applies here is. (Any help on this from others on the site?)

You could say,  "The subject of typography has always interested me". Or if you really wanted to use that word, you could rewrite the sentence to say, for example, "Spaces that are related to the subject of typography ..." But you can't say, "Spaces that are a subject of typography ..." That's just not idiomatic usage.

- You could say, "Bob and Sally are subjects of the United Kingdom", but that's an entirely different meaning of the word "subject".